# Proof verification for "$\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$" (without the well-ordering principle)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I've come across a lot of websites that were giving a proof of the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, but it seems to me that none of them was using only what we had already covered in my lecture, so I tried to prove it by myself (with what we had already seen). The thing is I don't know if it's correct or not, since I didn't find the same proof somewhere else.

So here we go: we want to show that for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x<y$, there exists $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<q<y$.

We're going to use:

1. the Archimedean property: for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > x$.
2. a consequence of the Archimedean property: if $x > 0$, then there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0 < \frac{1}{n} < x$.
3. the "completeness axiom": any non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded below has a greatest lower bound (infimum).

**And here is my proof:**

Since $x<y$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $0<y-x \in \mathbb{R}$. Because of the consequence of the Archimedean property, we have that $0 < \frac{1}{n} < y-x$.

Let's now consider the subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ defined by:

$A:=\{p \in \mathbb{Z} : p > nx \}$

We know that $nx \in \mathbb{R}$ since $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, because of the Archimedean property, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N > nx$, which means that $A$ is non-empty. By definition of $A$, there exists $\inf(A) = nx$. Therefore, by the completeness axiom, we have:

$\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists m \in A$ such that $nx+\epsilon > m \ge nx$

And because $nx$ does not belong to $A$, we actually have

$\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists m \in A$ such that $nx+\epsilon > m > nx$.

Because this is true for all $\epsilon$, let's consider, for example, $\epsilon = 1$. We have that $x > \frac{m-1}{n}$.

And here comes the conclusion: as $\frac{1}{n} < y-x$ and $m>nx$, we have:

$x < \frac{m}{n} = \frac{m-1+1}{n} = \frac{m-1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} < x + (y-x) = y$

$\Rightarrow x < \frac{m}{n} < y$, with $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So there exists $q = \frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<q<y$.

I don't know if everything is correct or if I missed something that I souldn't have. Any comment or correction would be welcome! (And sorry if this is the nth time someone asks something about this topic ; I just couldn't find exactly what I was looking for elsewhere.)

Comment: Nice proof and doubt about this sentence: $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists m \in A$ such that $nx+\epsilon > m > nx$.

Comment: @MyGlasses Thanks for your comment. The sentence you mention comes from my lecture: the sentence $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists m \in A$ such that $nx+\epsilon > m \ge nx$ is (apparently) the same as saying that $nx$ is the greatest lower bound of $A$. And in that case $nx$ does not belong to $A$, so you get the sentence you quoted.

But now that you mention it, I have to say I've never been 100% sure of why this sentence is equivalent to say that $nx$ is the greatest lower bound... I guess I should write another question for that.

Comment: Why is $\inf A=nx$?

Comment: @ryanblack That's a good question. I didn't even thought about that. Does that invalidate my proof or is there still hope for it?

Comment: What you have covered in the lecture? May I know?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan At that point we didn't have covered a lot: algebraic and order axioms of real numbers, some definitions and properties about those axioms and about the absolute value (including the triangle inequality for real numbers), and definitions of upper/lower bounds, infimum/supremum, Archimedean property and completeness axiom. The proof of the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ was given as an exercise but Jesus Christ it took me hours and apparently I still don't get it.

Comment: What is clear in your proof is that $nx$ is lower bound of $A$. Thus, $$nx\leq\inf A.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are, imo, several inaccurate things in the above after "And here is my proof":

(1) In the second line, I think you wanted to say  "..and thus there exists $\;n_0\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. $\;\cfrac1{n_0}<y-x\;$"

(2) Your definition of $\;A\;$ is, I think, depending on the **specific** $\;n_0\in\Bbb N\;$  whose existence was mentioned in (1),  *and* on the generic $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ you began with , so it should be

$$\;A_{0,x}:=\left\{\,p\in\Bbb Z\;/\;p>n_0x\,\right\}$$

(3) The infimum of $\;A_{0,x}\;$ is going to be its minimum as $\;A_{0,x}\subset\Bbb Z\;$ in fact, and we can point out *directly* this minimum:

$$\inf A=\lfloor n_0x\rfloor+1$$

Take into account thge above and try now to continue from here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess your point (3) comes from the well-ordering principle, which I didn't want to use because at that point we had not mentioned it in our lecture.. but maybe there is a way to deduce it from the completeness axiom? Or from something else?

For the ending... I'm stuck. If I understood well, we have $\inf A = \lfloor n_0 x \rfloor + 1$ because of the definition of the floor function. Therefore we can write: $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists m \in A_{0,x}$ such that $\lfloor n_0 x \rfloor + 1 + \epsilon > m \ge \lfloor n_0 x \rfloor + 1$.

Comment: Sorry, not enough characters left to write everything in one comment. We can substract 1 everywhere and we get $\lfloor n_0 x \rfloor + \epsilon > m-1 \ge \lfloor n_0 x \rfloor$. If $\epsilon = 1$, then $m-1 = n_0 x$.

Comment: Because of some editing time thing, I have to write another comment. Sorry for that.
$m-1 = n_0 x \Leftrightarrow \frac{m-1}{n_0} = x$. Because $m-1 < m$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $x = \frac{m-1}{n_0} < \frac{m}{n_0} = \frac{m-1+1}{n_0} = \frac{m-1}{n_0} + \frac{1}{n_0} < x + (y-x) = y$.

Is that it or did I made another mistake?

Comment: @alissad You can prove directly that $\;p\in A_{0,x}\implies p>nx\implies p\ge\lfloor nx\rfloor +1\;$ , since all the last inequality is in the integers...and from to deduce that that's the minimum, wihout using the well ordering principle of some (not all!) of the subsets of $\;\Bbb Z\;$ .

Comment: I think I got it this time. :) You're awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just realized there are still mistakes in what I've done in the comments above: I wrote that "if $\epsilon = 1$, then $m-1 = n_0 x$", which is wrong because $m-1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ while $n_0 x \in \mathbb{R}$. What would have been more correct is "if $\epsilon = 1$, then $m-1 = \lfloor n_0 x \rfloor$, but then it's difficult to conclude using what I wrote after that. Anyway, I think I found another way to prove the whole thing, so maybe I will edit my initial post with my "new proof", and I hope someone will still be there to check if, this time, I finally managed to do it :)

Comment: @alissad It may be a better idea to write a whole new post, asking for opinions for your new proof or stuff. If you want, you can link this question into your new one.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I'll do that then. See you around :)

Answer (score 0):

Without giving a definition of $\mathbb{R}$, it is not obvious if the part "We are going to use" uses circular logic or not.

A cleaner method is this: A metric space is dense in its completion, and $\mathbb{R}$ is by definition the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the usual metric (see "Construction from Cauchy sequences" in Wikipedia's "Construction of the real numbers").